# Expand only one table row at a time Ant Design React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

I'm unable to achieve that, I have attached the code below please let me know what's wrong here?

before adding `expandedRowKeys` and `onExpand` it was expanding all tables rows but after implementing it, it doesn't even open one row

```
<Table
    rowkey="id"
    size="small"
    columns={groupsPackageColumns}
    dataSource={roomPackages}
    className="taglist-table"
    expandable={{
        expandedRowRender: (record) => (
            <Table
                rowKey="id"
                columns={nestedTagsColumn}
                dataSource={record.tags}
                className="ant-table-container"
            />
        ),                    
        expandedRowKeys: activeExpRow,
        onExpand: (expanded, record) => {
            const keys = [];
            if (expanded) {
               keys.push(record.id); 
            }
            setActiveExpRow(keys);
        },
    }}
                        
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your `roomPackages`'s data structure.
But it should contain `key` property. and push `record.key`instead of `record.id`
If `dataSource` data doesn't include `key` property, you will get below error.
[image]

So, we need to modify the data as it includes `key` property.
I made the working Codesandbox.

https://codesandbox.io/s/expandable-row-antd-4-17-4-forked-41rd3?file=/index.js

Comment: instead of key I have `id` in my objects

Comment: I updated my Sandbox and description.